# toggle button issue when adding the script to hide while clicking outside orgchart

Tags: jquery

I'm working on jquery orgchart, based on https://rawgit.com/dabeng/OrgChart/master/demo/option-createNode.html
 Everything is working fine except some toggle button issue.
Using the above script, on clicking on 'i' the profile data is visible and toggle is working fine. But as per my requirement i have to make that button closed if i clicked somewhere else. 
So i made the below modifications and the menu is getting closed when i clicked out side , but the toggle button is not working.

Can anyone please help me with that.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
$(function() {

    var datascource = {
      'id': '1',
      'name': 'Lao Lao',
      'title': 'general manager',
      'children': [
        { 'id': '2', 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager',
          'children': [
            { 'id': '4', 'name': 'Tie Hua', 'title': 'senior engineer' },
            { 'id': '5', 'name': 'Hei Hei', 'title': 'senior engineer',
              'children': [
                { 'id': '6', 'name': 'Pang Pang', 'title': 'engineer' },
                { 'id': '7', 'name': 'Xiang Xiang', 'title': 'UE engineer' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        { 'id': '8', 'name': 'Yu Jie', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'id': '9', 'name': 'Yu Li', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'id': '10', 'name': 'Hong Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'id': '11', 'name': 'Yu Wei', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'id': '12', 'name': 'Chun Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'id': '13', 'name': 'Yu Tie', 'title': 'department manager' }
      ]
    };

    $('#chart-container').orgchart({
      'data' : datascource,
      'visibleLevel': 2,
      'nodeContent': 'title',
      'nodeID': 'id',
      'createNode': function($node, data) {
        var secondMenuIcon = $('<i>', {
          'class': 'fa fa-info-circle second-menu-icon',
          click: function(event) {
            $(this).siblings('.second-menu').toggle();
   event.stopPropagation();
          }
        });
        var secondMenu = '<div class="second-menu"><img class="avatar" src="img/avatar/' + data.id + '.jpg"></div>';
        $node.append(secondMenuIcon).append(secondMenu);
      }
    });

  });
  $(document).on("click", function (event) {
  $(".second-menu").hide();
 });
 $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
 
     e.preventDefault();
    var $menu = $('.second-menu');
    if (!$menu.is(e.target) 
    && $menu.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
    // if ( $menu.is( ":visible" )) {
        $(".second-menu").hide();
  //} else
  //{
   //$(".second-menu").show();
  //}

   }
   
  });
```

```css
.orgchart .second-menu-icon {
      transition: opacity .5s;
      opacity: 0;
      right: -5px;
      top: -5px;
      z-index: 2;
      color: rgba(68, 157, 68, 0.5);
      font-size: 18px;
      position: absolute;
    }
    .orgchart .second-menu-icon:hover { color: #449d44; }
    .orgchart .node:hover .second-menu-icon { opacity: 1; }
    .orgchart .node .second-menu {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: -70px;
      border-radius: 35px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px #999;
      background-color: #fff;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .orgchart .node .second-menu .avatar {
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      border-radius: 30px;
      float: left;
      margin: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.3/css/jquery.orgchart.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.3/js/jquery.orgchart.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
```

Thanks,
Sara.

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried and tell us why it did not work?

Comment: Initially the code the code has only toggle button.[code] click: function(event) {
            $(this).siblings('.second-menu').toggle();
   
          }  so i added  event.stopPropagation(); inside the click function. Also i tried the below code to hide the toggle button if it not the target. So now if i click anywhere on the page the profile icon will get close but when i click on it its doesnt toggle.

Comment: Can you please run the snippet to see the issue?

Comment: From what I understand from your question is that after clicking the "i" button it needs to pop up, then after the user clicks anywhere else the information frame needs to go away?

Comment: Yes, along with that when i click on 'i' button first time it should open then again if i click on it it should close (toggle).

Comment: In the code if i use toggle only that works. While adding code to hide the toggle div on clicking on outside, that makes the toggle  button issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the function that is associated with the `i` button being clicked is independent of the rest of the menus. When you click the `i` button it is only changing the state of the button that was clicked. the solution is to hide all of the objects with the `second-menu` class prior to toggling.

I removed the code that you had in your `$(document).mouseup()` function and placed it within the `secondMenuIcon.click()` function like so:

```
var secondMenuIcon = $('<i>', {
  'class': 'fa fa-info-circle second-menu-icon',
  click: function(event) {                                           
    if($(this).siblings('.second-menu').is( ":visible" )){          
      $(this).siblings('.second-menu').hide();                  
    }else{
      $('.second-menu').hide();                    
      $(this).siblings('.second-menu').show();                  
    }                      
    event.stopPropagation();                   
}
```

Finally, I changed the way that if you click anywhere on the document works.

```
$(document).on("click", function(event) {
  $('.second-menu').hide();
});
```

Of course you I posted the full example to JS Fiddle you can 
[edit it in JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/x6zoq23a/21/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=x6zoq23a)

---

Alternatively you could use hover instead which is (in my opinion) easier,

```
var secondMenuIcon = $('<i>', {
  'class': 'fa fa-info-circle second-menu-icon',
  hover: function(event) {                                           
    $(this).siblings('.second-menu').show();                                                  
    event.stopPropagation();                   
  },
  mouseleave: function(event) {                                           
    $(this).siblings('.second-menu').hide();                                                  
    event.stopPropagation();                   
  }
});
```

I also posted the hover example to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfqbhgsy/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=Lfqbhgsy)

---

*Note:* I am not an expert with jQuery I am sure there is a more efficient way to do this. This is what I could come up with, using my limited knowledge of jQuery

Comment: Hi Suit , Thanks for the solution. Its works after loading for the first time. When i expanded the nodes and on second level, if i click on 'i'  the profile  image is not poped up.

Comment: It is late where I am. I am going to bed. I did delete this line of code if(!$menu.is(e.target) && $menu.has(e.target).length ==o) for my own testing. Try adding that back in. If not let me know and I’ll get back to you tomorrow

Comment: Thank you So much. I tired adding that also but issue still persists.

Comment: I updated my answer, I tested it in JSFiddle and it appears to be working perfectly for me. You may also want to consider using mouse hover to hide and show the second-menu instead. r

Comment: Done. Thank you so much for your help.